# How to list Windows Services from within a Service

Tags: windows, service, windows-services

`sc query state= all` works as expected from the command line.

From within another Service, `sc query state= all` doesn't print anything to that sub-process' stdout (captured by the parent, of course).

Is there a permission/privilege that the Service needs in order to list/start/stop the other servies?

---

A little background: I am making a service that periodically restarts some misbehaving services.

Comment: Hmm, after writing my answer I noticed you didn't even specify the programming language you used.

Comment: First, check that your code works when run as a regular application rather than as a service.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one don't do that, at least not in a blocking manner. In order for your own service to respond to the SCM (Service Control Manager) in order to return its status, the service has to be able to execute its dispatcher code. This means that if you call this program and wait for it to exit you'll wait indefinitely. One way to mitigate this would be to put this into a separate thread so it's not blocking your dispatching and your service will continue to talk to the SCM.

Alternatively (and probably better) you could use the `EnumServicesStatusEx` function to talk to the SCM and inquire about the statuses of other services yourself. The function itself doesn't mention anything about being blocking, so you'd have to figure out yourself whether it is and then use a thread again to prevent your service from stopping to talk to the SCM.

One last note: **if those misbehaving services are yours, you should more likely fix the respective code**. I've had a share of legacy code and had one misbehaving service which got its own helper application as "fault action" (can be configured in service configuration as `SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS`) that would go about and restart the service whenever it crashed. Once I took that code over, figured out the cause and fixed it, the service was stable again and that application isn't really needed anymore.

Comment: The dispatcher calls always happen in a separate thread, so it doesn't matter if the ServiceMain thread blocks.

Comment: @Harry Johnston: well, since he does not show *where* he invokes the process, I didn't want to assume that. But thanks for the clarification.